# Getting exact copy of a React Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an IDE-like software for React development and I want to enable an **undo** functionality
This would basically help someone go back to their previous component tree when they press Ctrl-Z
For this I was hoping to save the history of the React Element on which Undo would happen.

I kept updating the history at intervals of 1000 ms;

```
cloned = React.cloneElement(this.ele);
this.history.push(cloned);
```

In my undo code I simply set `this.ele` to the first element in `this.history` queue (only for testing purposes)
Something like this:

```
this.ele = this.history.pop();
```

Render function:

```
render()   {
    this.ele = React.createElement(getComponent(this.props.componentName), this.state.propsToSend, precomputedChildren);

    return(
        <div>{this.ele}</div>
    );
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. One thing is `React.createElement` is being called every time render() is invoked. I tried doing that in constructor but that doesn't give any results.

**So my questions is:**
How to create an exact deep copy of a React Component Tree. `React.cloneElement` doesn't seem to work.
Thanks a lot.